# winform webbrowser not replaced

Tags: c#, winforms, class, browser, webbrowser-control

From my `Form1` I initialize a class `scraper`. In the `scraper` class is an function `login`. The idea is that that class log's the user in on an website, and returned the web browser so that an logged in webbrowser control is available in `Form1`.

I've got this code so far: `Form1`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Scraper scraper = new Scraper(this);
    scraper.login(conf._webLogin);  
}

public void updateLoginWeb(WebBrowser web)
{
    webBrowser1 = web;
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

The conf class:

```
public WebBrowser _webLogin = new WebBrowser();
```

The scraper class:

```
private Form1 parent;

private WebBrowser _web_Login = new WebBrowser();


public Scraper()
{

}

public Scraper(Form1 parent)
    : this()
{
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void login(WebBrowser web)
{
    _web_Login = web;
    _web_Login.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(login_DocumentCompleted);
    _web_Login.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
}

private void login_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //This line is so you only do the event once   
    if (e.Url != _web_Login.Url)
        return;
    parent.updateLoginWeb(_web_Login);
}
```

I use google as test, but nothing works (not even an another site).

The problem is that the webbrowser in the `Form` isn't updated. It's still an white screen.

What do you guys think of this? Do you know what the problem is or do you guys know an better way to handle this?

Comment: do you have cross thread call to web browser?

Comment: @user64, nope. Just this 1 thing that get's fired by an button...

Comment: does webbrowser is running on UI thread? does webbrowser using proxy? Check if google.com is shown in IE

Comment: @user64, yes, it's running in the UI thread, no the webbrowser doens't use proxy

Comment: @Shaeldon, if you are going to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7374284) posts based on a [clean up request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288197/1043380), edit the _entire_ post. Don't just remove a few lines. I Reject and Edited a good number of your suggested edits. This is one I would have also rejected if I saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you can not simply assign the webBrowser variable:

```
webBrowser1 = web;
```

You are changing the Form1.webBrower1 variable, but the Forms.Controls collection is still pointing to the original webBrowser control.

Can't you just pass Form1.webBrower1 to scraper.login function?:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Scraper scraper = new Scraper(this);
    scraper.login(webBrowser1);  
}

public void updateLoginWeb(WebBrowser web)
{
    //webBrowser1 = web;  // you don't need this anymore
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

If you really need to replace your control you can do something like:

```
public void updateLoginWeb(WebBrowser web)
{
    Controls.Remove(webBrowser1);
    Controls.Add(web);
    webBrowser1 = web;  // you don't need this anymore
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

But you will probably to set the new webbrowser layout properties manually.

Comment: Alright, but how do i get the webbrowser in wich i worked ( logged in and al that kind of stuff ) back to Form1 display. Or do you know that the cookies are shared. So that when i log in ( it's cookie based ), i'm also logged in on any other webbrowser control ( even if i create that one later on )

Comment: Can't you just use only one WebBrowser control? the Form1.webBrowser1, and use it in the scraper class? dont create a different one

Comment: Well, the thing is that i might end up doing 2 or more things at 1 moment with the webbrowser. So i need multiple for each task...

Comment: You can't isolate multiple "sessions" within a single process. WinINET (and thus the web browser control) shares cookies process-wide.

Comment: @EricLaw, so if i create an webbrowser ( `new webBrowser` ) and login in the scrapper, and later on in an another class i create an another webbrowser ( in another class ). then i'm still loged in???

Comment: Yes, basically it will behave as if you open a new tab in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @fcuesta, thank you very much. I'll accept your answer and play with this ( first code clean-up and sleep time :D ). Thanks